# How to access the Wine directory from Dash

Tags: 11.10, wine

Before Unity I could go to the main menu and navigate to the "C:" folder when Wine has all the programs. Using Unity and the Dash how can I get to the wine directory quickly since right now what I am doing is going to Nautilus, pressing CTRL+L and addint .wine to the location bar so it looks something like /home/cyrex/.wine and then clicking on the drive_c there to enter the real directory I want.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well it might look like I was not even paying attention to what I was asking here but it just came to me to type **drive** in the dash and what do you know, look at this:

[image]

The **Browse C: Drive** option appears and you can even drag it to the launcher. So it not only does work with Dash but you can also add it to the launcher to speed things up when I want to go inside the C: drive. Love Unity more and more.

Comment: Typing in simply "c" points you first to Browse C: Drive.

Comment: @Satchit - Can't get any more smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /usr/share/applications/nautilus-home.desktop

For syntax see - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-folder-quicklists-to-the-home-launcher-in-ubuntu-unity/

Comment: I do not mean the launcher, I mean the DASH search tool. So when I look for the wine directory it shows me some kind of access for it. For example if I type wine it shows winecfg, winetricks and wine uninstall. But how to add a way to show "Drive C" or something to it that points to the wine directory directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real good way yet. (bugs have been filed about no wine specific choice in Dash > Files and Folders

If you open Dash > click on Files & Folders icon you should be able to search "drive" & have drive_c show up in the results.

To do so you need to do 2 things. First - no folder will show unless you've opened a file directly in that folder.

By default drive_c has no files in it, so go to drive_c, create an empty file & open it in a text editor.

2nd - when searching in 'Find files' (Files & Folders), you need to "Filter results" > Type > Folders

If you do both of the above then drive_c should show after dr in the search box.

Not really much of a solution...

An alternate - 
Go to drive_c, create a very uniquely named text file & open it in a text editor.

Then you could simply open Dash > find files, search it & D&D the file from the dash on to the home folder icon in unity launcher. A nautilus window will open @ drive_c

To enable this to work correctly in 11.10 you need the Exec= line in nautilus-home.desktop to end in %U as in

```
Exec=nautilus %U
```